# Django rest framework - model serializer doesn't serialize all fields

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework 3.7.7

I want to serialize an object instance and then deserialize it (without saving to DB again).
So I created a serializer that inherits from serializers.ModelSerializer.
To this model instance I sometimes add a field within the request that is not part of the model, using property setter. I did add it to the serializer as well, but when serializing - I don't see that field in the serialized data.

This is the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    manager = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    reviewer = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def note(self):
        return getattr(self, '_note', None)

    @note.setter
    def note(self, value):
        self._note = value
```

This is the model serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    note = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False, max_length=1000, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'manager',
            'reviewer',
            'note'
        ]
```

This is how I use the serializer:

```
ser_instance = MyModelSerializer(self.instance)
ser_data = ser_instance.data
```

seems like the `ser_instance.data` contains only the model fields data (without the 'note')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [**`write_only`**--[DRF-Doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only), it states that

> Set this to **`True`** to ensure that the field may be used when updating or creating an instance, but is not included when serializing the representation.
>
> Defaults to **`False`**

---

So, if you need to serialize the **`note`** field, remove the **`write_only=true`** from serializer.

```
#serializers.py
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    note = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=1000, allow_null=True)  # removed "write_only=True"
    ...
```